# Store Map entries in file and read those back in

Tags: java, dictionary, file-io, hashmap, bufferedreader

I have declared a map like below and filled this with Value and Keys.

```
Map<String,List<String>> cat = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

I can successfully write this to a file like this:

```
try{
        File SubCats = new File("subcats.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(SubCats);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);

            for(Map.Entry<String,List<String>> m :cat.entrySet()) {
                pw.println(m.getKey()+"="+m.getValue());
            }

            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            fos.close();
        }
```

My question now is how to read this back into the map from the file. I trying something like this, but do not know how to 'put' the Value and Keys back in.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("subcats.txt"));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String parts[] = line.split("\t");

            for(Map.Entry<String,List<String>> m :cat.entrySet()) {
                (m.putKey(), m.putValue());
            }
        in.close();
        }
```

Thx.

Comment: Why do you split on tab? Why don't you split on `=` instead, since that's the separator between the key and the value? Why do you think you need to iterate on the entrySet of the map to add a key/value pair to the map? Note that your strategy is full of problems: what if the key or the value contains an `=`, or if it contains multiple lines? Or if it contains a character that is not supported by the default charset of your platform?I would serialize the map to JSON instead.

Comment: I am afraid you're completely right. This is not going to work as the file I am trying to read is formatted like this: Fruits=[Apple, Pear, Banana, Mango, Orange].

Comment: @markknaap see my answer it should work, your comment indicates the delimiter is `",\t"`, if not I can easily adjust.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Map<String, List<String>> readSubCats() throws IOException {
    Map<String, List<String>> ret = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("subcats.txt"));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        int i = line.indexOf("=");
        // if i < 0 throw an Exception
        ret.put(line.substring(0, i), Arrays.asList(line.substring(i + 2, line.length() - 1).split(",\\t")));
    }
    in.close();
    return ret;
}
```

This will only work if you don't have any `\n` and `\t` in your Strings in the List and no `=` in the key, other characters are fine.

Note that `split` expects a regular expression, a tab in regex is like in Java `\t`, but because `\` is the escape character in Java we need to escape itself, which leads `\\t`. If you want to split by `\` then you have to write `split("\\\\")` because `\` is also the escape character in regex.

Comment: sorry for late reply, had a few busy days. Used your code as proposed and works like a charm. Many thanks.

Comment: @markknaap you're welcome. If it solved your question then please accept it as answer (the grey checkmark sign).